# If $T: R^n \rightarrow R^k$ is affine, then $T(x)=\lambda(x) + y_0$, where $\lambda:R^n \rightarrow R^k$ is a linear map and $y_0$ fixed.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> If $T: R^n \rightarrow R^k$ is affine, then $T(x)=\lambda(x) + y_0$, where $\lambda:R^n \rightarrow R^k$ is a linear transformation and $y_0 $ is fixed.

The book hints at letting $y_0=T(0)$, so then $\lambda(x) = T(x)-T(0)$ should be the map.

So $\lambda(ax)=a\lambda(x)$ should be true and therefore:

$\lambda(a\sum t_i p_i)=T(a \sum t_ip_i)-T(0)=a\sum t_iT(p_i)-T(0)$

and $a\lambda(x) = a[T(\sum t_ip_i)-T(0)] = a\sum t_i T(p_i)-aT(0)$

But these are only equal if $T(0)=0$, so my question is:  Is this correct?  Because these seems to be trivial to say something + $0$ is itself.

Comment: Isn't the statement obvious because all affine maps are translational?

Comment: What are $t_i$ and $p_i$?

Comment: @amd Since the map is affine, elements of the domain are affine combinations of some set of points.

Comment: @ALB So is my proof correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @OliverG I see no issue, but it seems as if the "hint" should be called "solution".

Comment: @ALB Would there be any other linear maps and conditions for $y_0$ that wouldn't be trivial?

Comment: What is your definition of affine?

Comment: The function is affine meaning an affine map.

Comment: @OliverG yeah, what is your definition of an affine map? Depending on it your proof may be not correct.

Comment: @user251257 Let $\{p_0, ..., p_n\} \subset R^n$ be affine independent and let $A$ denote the affine set it spans.  An affine map $T: A \rightarrow R^k$ (for some $k \gt 1$) is a function satisfying $T(\sum t_ip_i) = \sum t_i T(p_i)$ whenever $\sum t_i=1$.

Comment: Then how do you get $T(a\sum t_ip_i) = a \sum t_i T(p_i)$? I would try to show that $\lambda$ is affine and $\lambda(0) = 0$, which implies that $\lambda$ is linear.

Comment: @user251257 How does $\lambda$ being affine and $\lambda(0) = 0$ implies $\lambda$ is linear?  Showing $\lambda$ is linear means showing $T(ax) - T(0) = a[T(x) - T(0)]$, but how would I show this is true from here since I'm left with the same problem $T(a\sum t_ip_i)$ vs. $a\sum t_i T(p_i)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition 1:** Let $\lambda : V \to W$ be an affine map from $k$ vector space $V$ into $k$ vector space $W$. Then, $\lambda$ is linear if and only if $\lambda(0)=0$.

*Proof:* If $\lambda$ is linear, then $\lambda(0)=0$ holds trivially. On other hand, if $\lambda(0)=0$ holds, we have
\begin{align*} 
\lambda(r u + sv) &= \lambda(r u + sv + (1-r-s)0) \\
&= r\lambda(u) + s\lambda(v) + (1-r-s)\lambda(0) \\
&= r\lambda(u) + s\lambda(v)
\end{align*}
for $r,s\in k$ and $u,v\in V$.

**Proposition 2:** Let $T:V\to W$ be a map from $k$ vector space $V$ into $k$ vector space $W$. Then, $T$ is affine if and only if $\lambda = T - T(0)$ is linear.

*Proof:* If $T$ is affine, then $\lambda$ is affine, as for $r\in k$ and $u,v\in V$ we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda(ru+(1-r)v) &=  T(ru+(1-r)v) - T(0) \\
&=  T(ru+(1-r)v) - (r + (1-r))T(0) \\
&= rT(u) + (1-r)T(v) - rT(0) - (1-r)T(0) \\
&= r(T(u) - T(0)) + (1-r)(T(v) - T(0)) \\
&= r\lambda(u) + (1-r)\lambda(v),
\end{align*}
and $\lambda(0) = 0$.
On other hand, if $\lambda$ is linear, then  $T = \lambda + T(0)$ is trivially affine.

Comment: How does $T$ being affine imply that $T(ru + (1-r)v)  = rT(u)+(1-r)T(v)$?  $T$ being affine means $T: \text{affine span($\{a_0, ..., a_m\}$}) \rightarrow R^k$, where $T( \sum_i t_i  a_i) = \sum_i t_i T(a_i)$ when $\sum_i t_i = 1$ and $\{a_0, ..., a_m\}$ is affine independent?

Comment: @OliverG if $u,v$ are from the affine span, then there are $t_i$ and $\tilde t_i$ such $\sum_i t_i a_i = u$, $\sum_i t_i = 1$, $\sum_i \tilde t_i a_i = u$, $\sum_i \tilde t_i = 1$. Thus, $ru + (1-r) v = \sum_i (rt_i + (1-r)\tilde t_i)a_i$ with $\sum_i (rt_i + (1-r)\tilde t_i) = r + (1-r) = 1$. Use that to compute $T(ru + (1-r)v)$.